# Save List to SharedPreferences in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, gson, sharedpreferences

Im trying to save list data in preferences

```
List<AppGrid> mArrayProducts = new ArrayList<AppGrid>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonObject = gson.toJson(mArrayProducts);
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("MyObject", jsonObject);
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(InstalledAppActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

> AppGrid.java

```
private String dataDir;
private Drawable icon;
private String id;
private String name;
private String launcherName;
private String packageName;
private int pageIndex;
private int position;
private boolean sysApp;
public boolean selected;
public AppGrid() {

}


public AppGrid(Drawable icon, String title, String packageName) {
    this.icon = icon;
    this.name = title;
    this.packageName = packageName;
}
protected AppGrid(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    packageName = in.readString();
    selected = in.readByte() != 0;
}


public String getDataDir() {
    return this.dataDir;
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return this.icon;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getPackageName() {
    return this.packageName;
}

public int getPageIndex() {
    return this.pageIndex;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return this.position;
}

public void setDataDir(String paramString) {
    this.dataDir = paramString;
}

public void setIcon(Drawable paramDrawable) {
    this.icon = paramDrawable;
}

public void setId(String paramString) {
    this.id = paramString;
}

public void setName(String paramString) {
    this.name = paramString;
}

public void setPackageName(String paramString) {
    this.packageName = paramString;
}

public void setPageIndex(int paramInt) {
    this.pageIndex = paramInt;
}

public void setPosition(int paramInt) {
    this.position = paramInt;
}

public String toString() {
    return "AppGrid [packageName=" + this.packageName + ", name=" + this.name + ", icon=" + this.icon + ", dataDir=" + this.dataDir + "]";
}

public boolean isSysApp() {
    return sysApp;
}

public void setSysApp(boolean sysApp) {
    this.sysApp = sysApp;
}

public String getLauncherName() {
    return launcherName;
}

public void setLauncherName(String launcherName) {
    this.launcherName = launcherName;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(packageName);
   /* Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)((BitmapDrawable) icon ).getBitmap();
    parcel.writeParcelable(bitmap, i);*/
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (selected ? 1 : 0));
}
public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public static final Creator<AppGrid> CREATOR = new Creator<AppGrid>() {
    @Override
    public AppGrid createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new AppGrid(in);
    }

    @Override
    public AppGrid[] newArray(int size) {
        return new AppGrid[size];
    }
};
```

}

Data is not saving in shared preferences.Could you please help me

Logcat:

> D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a
>   16 byte allocation with 4194272 free bytes and 4MB until OOM; failed
>   due to fragmentation (required continguous free 4096 bytes for a new
>   buffer where largest contiguous free 0 bytes)

Comment: What is the size of the list ?

Comment: What type of data Class AppGrid contain?

Comment: I have added AppGrid.calss ,could u please find

Comment: I think you are saving Drawable so you are getting OutOfMemory Eexcption. Try to save the image path in Sharedpreference not the image.

Comment: i am doing this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305935/model-view-presenter-possession-is-not-chaging-in-android-application

Comment: @shawon  i have used bundle also data saving but receiving side NULL is coming.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to saving a very large value. SharedPreferences is not used for storing data. it just store simple data. It is designed to store small, key value pairs such as settings , user names , ids , options etc.

Technically, all shared prefs are stored in /data/data/[package name]/shared_prefs/[app name].xml, so i think there's no limit based on architecture.

But some devices might have difficulties and performance issues on this matter. thus, basically there is a limitations of SharedPreference data for few devices

So its better to use SQLite database when you have to deal with huge amount of data.

EDIT

If i not mistaken, you are trying to store drawable icon which might lead large byte stored. best practices is just store the IDs of the drawable only..

```
public class AppGrid {

    private String dataDir;
    private int Drawableicon;
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String launcherName;
    private String packageName;
    private int pageIndex;
    private int position;
    private boolean sysApp;
    public boolean selected;


    public AppGrid(@drawable int icon, String title, String packageName) {
        this.Drawableicon = icon;
        this.name = title;
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    //setter and getter
}
```

just create simple model class. no need Parcel..

Comment: Before this I have used sqlite but problem is,If user is uninstall  favourite apps,still that app is showing because that app information still in sqlite. So now im using shared pref.I going correct way?? could u please guide me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305935/model-view-presenter-possession-is-not-chaging-in-android-application